# How can I search for a file in which an element does not appear?

Tags: linux, grep

how can I search for a file in which an element does not appear?
This means that there are various text files in a directory.
Most of them contain the element "das_auto".
But I would like to have all files listed that do not have the element "das_auto".
What can the search term look like?

I have already tried the following search query:

```
egrep -Rni --color -o --include=only_text_file.txt -v 'das_auto' filesEdit
```

Unfortunately without success.

Comment: Look into the `-L, --files-without-match` option of (gnu) grep.

Answer (score 0):

thanks **@Roadowl** for the tip, it worked.
Here is my solution:

```
egrep -R -L --color --include=only_text_file.txt 'das_auto' filesEdit
```